# Union of preimages of edge coloring

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and $c:E \rightarrow [\chi'(G)]$ be an edge coloring with chromatic index $\chi'(G)$.

It is obvious that the preimage $c^{-1}(i),i\in [\chi'(G)]$ is a matching, but what can I say about the union of two such matchings $c^{-1}(i)\cup c^{-1}(j)$? Does the fact that $c$ is a proper edge coloring provide more information than just "it is a union of two matchings"?

Comment: Yes. Observe that, for example, no edge can have two colors, i.e. $c^{-1}(i)$ and $c^{-j}(j)$ are edge-disjoint for any $i \neq j$.